# Send data from contact.js to form process.php

Tags: javascript, php, sendmail, contact-form, mail-form

Hello i'm new in coding and making some project for practicing, i have some problem with contact form please help if you can

i'm validating contact form in js and want to send it on mail with php
i don't want that php took values from html, i'd like it to take from js cause js already has values at that time

and i can't figure out how to do that (php took mail form from js)

**here is my js file:**

```
function validateName() {

    var name = document.getElementById('contact-name').value;
  
    if(name.length < 2) {
  
      producePrompt('გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ სწორი სახელი', 'name-error' , 'red')
      return false;
  
    }
  
    if (!name.match(/^[A-Za-z]*/)) {
  
      producePrompt('გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ სწორი სახელი','name-error', 'red');
      return false;
  
    }
  
    producePrompt('მიღებულია', 'name-error', 'green');
    return true;
  
  }
  
  function validatePhone() {
  
    var phone = document.getElementById('contact-phone').value;
  
      if(phone.length < 6) {
        producePrompt('გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ სწორი ნომერი', 'phone-error', 'red');
        return false;
      }
  
     // if(phone.length != 10) {
      //  producePrompt('Include area code.', 'phone-error', 'red');
       // return false;
      //}
  
      if(!phone.match(/^\d{1,15}$/)) {
        producePrompt('გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ მხოლოდ ციფრები.' ,'phone-error', 'red');
        return false;
      }
  
      producePrompt('მიღებულია', 'phone-error', 'green');
      return true;
  
  }
  
  function validateEmail () {
  
    var email = document.getElementById('contact-email').value;
  
    if(email.length == 0) {
  
      producePrompt('მეილი არასწორია','email-error', 'red');
      return false;
  
    }
  
    if(!email.match(/^[A-Za-z\._\-[0-9]*[@][A-Za-z]*[\.][a-z]{2,4}$/)) {
  
      producePrompt('მეილი არასწორია', 'email-error', 'red');
      return false;
  
    }
  
    producePrompt('მიღებულია', 'email-error', 'green');
    return true;
  
  }

  function validateSubject() {
    var subject = document.getElementById('msg-subject').value;
    var required = 10;
    var left = required - subject.length;
  
    if (left > 0) {
      producePrompt(left + 'გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ მინიმუმ 10 სიმბოლო','message-error','red');
      return false;
    }
  
    producePrompt('მიღებულია', 'message-error', 'green');
    return true;
  
  }
  
  function validateMessage() {
    var message = document.getElementById('contact-message').value;
    var required = 30;
    var left = required - message.length;
  
    if (left > 0) {
      producePrompt(left + 'გთხოვთ შეიყვანოთ მინიმუმ 30 სიმბოლო','message-error','red');
      return false;
    }
  
    producePrompt('მიღებულია', 'message-error', 'green');
    return true;
  
  }
  
  function validateForm() {
    if (!validateName() || !validatePhone() || !validateEmail() || !validateSubject() || !validateMessage()) {
      jsShow('submit-error');
      producePrompt('გთხოვთ შეავსოთ ყველა ველი სწორად და სცადოთ ხელახლა', 'submit-error', 'red');
      setTimeout(function(){jsHide('submit-error');}, 2000);
        return false;
    }
    else {
  
    }
  }
  
  function jsShow(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
  }
  
  function jsHide(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  }
  
  
  
  
  function producePrompt(message, promptLocation, color) {
  
    document.getElementById(promptLocation).innerHTML = message;
    document.getElementById(promptLocation).style.color = color;
  
  
  }

  function submitForm(){
    validateName();
    validatePhone();
    validateEmail ();
    validateSubject();
    
  }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/assets/php/form-process.php",
            data:  SubmitForm,
            success : function(result){
                if (result == 'success'){
                    $('.output_message').text('მეილი მიღებულია');  
                } else {
                    $('.output_message').text('მეილის გაგზავნისას დაფიქსირდა შეცდომა');
                }
            }
        });
```

**here is my php file:**

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "დაფიქსირდა შეცდომა, სცადეთ ხელახლა";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["contact-name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["contact-name"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["contact-email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["contact-email"];
}

// MSG SUBJECT
if (empty($_POST["msg_subject"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Subject is required ";
} else {
    $msg_subject = $_POST["msg_subject"];
}

// PHONE-NUMBER
if (empty($_POST["contact-phone"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Number is required ";
} else {
    $phone_number = $_POST["contact-phone"];
}

// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["contact-message"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Message is required ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["contact-message"];
}

//Add your email here
$EmailTo = "test@gmail.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Subject: ";
$Body .= $msg_subject;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Phone-Number: ";
$Body .= $phone_number;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please clarify where you're stuck and where to so we don't have to read through it and guess what your actual issue is.

Comment: i think there is some issue in ajax i wanted not to use it but can`t find any other way
also i think php is looking for values in html but don`t know how to get values from js not from html

Comment: But what actually happens? You say you have an issue, but you haven't told us _what_ that issue is? Is it the ajax call that doesn't being sent? Is it PHP that gets the information wrong/missing info? Is it the email that doesn't send? `data:  SubmitForm`, where is `SubmitForm` defined and what does it contain?

Comment: Your `$.ajax` call appears to “hang in thin air”, it it not wrapped in any function - so it will execute when that script file loads, and at that time, you probably haven’t even entered any data into the form yet.

Comment: browser says some error in ajax on line data, try to send mail but nothing is sent also no any error on website shown

Comment: _"browser says some error in ajax on line data"_ - Please edit your question to include the full error message. It's pretty hard for us to help you sort out a, for us, completely unknown issue. Also, did you read what @CBroe noticed about the Ajax request? if it gets triggered on load, then the user won't have had a chance to enter anything. And I still have no clue where the variable `SubmitForm` you're sending in the request comes from or contains. There are too many unknowns here.